# I am getting the error message "Unexpected token: elif" in godot. Any tips?

Tags: godot

```
func _process(delta):

var velocity = Vector2()  

if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
    velocity.x += 1
if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
    velocity.x -= 1
if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_down"):
    velocity.y += 1
if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_up"):
    velocity.y -= 1
if velocity.length() > 1:
    velocity = velocity.normalized() * speed
    $AnimatedSprite.play()
else:
    $AnimatedSprite.stop()
position += velocity * delta
position.x = clamp(position.x, 0, screen_size.x)
position.y = clamp(position.y, 0, screen_size.y)
if velocity.x != 0:
    $AnimatedSprite.animation = "walk"
$AnimatedSprite.flip_v = false
$AnimatedSprite.flip_h = velocity.x < 0                              
    elif velocity.y != 0:
 $AnimatedSprite.animation = "up"
 $AnimatedSprite.flip_v = velocity.y > 0
```

line 20, any tips?

Answer (score 5):

Indentation matters in gdscript; make sure your code is indented correctly so that the `elif` is at the same depth as the `if`.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks

Comment: @JohnH. When this answer answered your question, please accept it by clicking the checkmark-icon next to it.